# Learn Python The Hard Way: Exercise 43 Function Creation

Tags: python, getattr

```
while True:
    print "\n--------"
    room = getattr(self, next)
    next = room()
```

My question stems from the block of code above, found in [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) - [Exercise 43](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html). I understand that the third line stores the `getattr()` function results (in this case, `self.next`) into the `room` variable (unless I'm wrong there...?)

What is hanging me up right now is the fourth line, where the function `room()` is stored into the variable `next`. Fundamentally, I don't understand the `room()` part as this isn't a defined function in the code block. Does Python allow the user to define a function based on a preceding variable? (For example: writing `room()` for the first time creates a function called `room()` based on what is stored in the variable `room`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

```
room = getattr(self, next)
```

Returns a *function*, which is then callable.

```
next = room()
```

Functions are first class objects in python, so they can be passed around as such. Handy!

Consider the following:

```
>>> class foo:
      def bar(self):
        print 'baz!'
      def __init__(self):
        # Following lines do the same thing!
        getattr(self, 'bar')()
        self.bar() 
>>> foo()
baz!
baz!
<__main__.foo instance at 0x02ADD8C8>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and clearing that. I understand that gettr() returns a function and that they can be stored. But in the code above, no function is called, correct? The reason I ask is because in example 43 the next step in the coded story/game proceeds to be printed out. If you look at the code, how does the program move from the play() to central_corridor()? I'm used to seeing functions called through code simply as: self.central_corridor() instead of what play() provides (which I just see as functions being stored as opposed to being called).

Comment: To clarify the above question: does next = room() run the room() function and store the results into the variable next?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what is happening.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the response.